# Upload image PHP problem

Tags: php, image, upload

Hi guys I'm using this code http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp to upload files and it works great but now I'm doing a form with an optional image and it won't let me upload. It says it's an invalid file format since it's no file at all. How do I check if there is a file to upload or not and then skip the upload script if there is none?

Thanks!

Note: I have removed the size limitation from the script if that makes any differance.

Comment: Well it has some good info for beginners, but otherwise i kinda agree with these guys: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Haha, I guess it't not the most advanced stuff in the world but I didn't understand anything on the other sites I found so...

Comment: BTW Thanks for the heads up cuz I thought was a part af W3C just becouse of it's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($_FILES['nameofyourfileinput']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   ... file has been uploaded and everything went ok ...
} else if ($_FILES['nameofyourfieinput']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
   ... something OTHER than a 'no file was uploaded' error has occured...
}
```

Upload error codes defined [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: What does three = in a row mean?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php   It's the "strict comparison". compares type AND value. PHP evaluates `0 == false` as true because false will convert to 0 (or 0 to false). saying `0 === false` will fail, because the types of the two are different, even if the values come out the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the file's error code isnt 4;
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php